# Interrupted git pull

Tags: git

I had a git pull that was interrupted and now I'm unsure if it has messed with my .git directory. Can I guarantee the integrity of my git repo by running `git fsck --full` ? Are there any other commands to see if something was not half added to the directory ?

Answer (score 0):

Make a physical copy of the the project (which will include its .git directory) to another place, say ~/tmp then run git pull there and see what it tells you.  You are only pulling and this is a throw-away directory so you will be insulated from changing anything (as long as you don't push without being sure).

So, if you application directory is: ~/blogger

do

```
cd ~                 # "~" means your home directory
mkdir tmp            # Make a temporary directory.
cp -r blogger ~/tmp  # Copy the project there
cd /tmp/blogger      # Go there
git pull             # Try a pull to see what happens.
```

If the pull works ok you'll have confidence in your actual directory contents (so `cd` back to it now).
If the pull has issues, save your current project code and try a fresh pull and see if that is ok.

e.g.

```
cd ~
mv blogger old_blogger
# Go to github and click on the copy icon.
git clone [paste - ctrl-v or shift-ctrl-v]
# Now use your old_blogger directory as a source 
# for any changes you want to (manually) copy the code from.
```

If a fresh `git pull` has issues, consider going to your project directory and deleting the entire `.git` structure and then `git init` to create a new git repository and then delete (or rename to old_blogger) the existing github one, create it anew and `git clone` again then `git add .`,  `git commit` and `git push`.  This is obviosuly the most extreme ('nuclear') option.